# Knowing the user input, how do i reference that cell to change its font color?

Tags: excel, vba

Here are the steps I am to follow. Can someone check my work and help me on step 2 and 4!!!! Please and thank you.

**Step 1:** Insert a procedure.  Ask a user to enter a number for a student as well as for a quiz using two input boxes.

**Step 2:** Knowing the student number and quiz number, change the color of the font for student grade to blue.

**Step 3:** Add code to insert the label Average in Cell M1 and boldface it.

**Step 4:** Enter a formula in column M for the student in Step 2 that averages his or her quiz grades.

```
Public Sub part3()
Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Name = "num"
Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Name = "student"
Range("c1:l1").End(xlToRight).Name = "quizzes"

Dim studentnum As Variant, quiznum As Variant
studentnum = InputBox("Please enter a student number.", , "10")
quiznum = InputBox("Now enter a quiz number.", , "8")

Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range
For Each cell In Range("num")
cntr = cntr + 1

   If UCase(studentnum) = UCase(cell.Value) Then
    cntr2 = cntr2 + 1
        If UCase(quiznum) = UCase(cell2.Value) Then
            .Font.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    Next cell2
End If
Next cell
End If



Range("m1").Value = "Average"
    With Range("m1")
        .Name = "Average"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

'step4
?????????

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to pass your course, so I will try to make these comments fairly generic - Step 2:  Try to find the `Row` of the cell where the entered student number matches the value in your `num` range.  Try to find the `Column` of the cell where the entered quiz number matches the value in your `quizzes` range.  The cell which has a row number, column number that equals the row and column you determined is the one that needs to be set to blue.  Step 4: The cell which has a row number that matches the row you determined (and is in column M) is the one where you need to insert a `Formula`.

Comment: This is a practice test for a real one I have tomorrow morning so you wouldn't be passing my course for me. I don't understand the way to write what column and row. Am i correct with the For Each? can you tell me what is wrong with my step 2 section?

Answer (score 0):

Your step 2 should be something like:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
For Each cell In Range("num")
    If UCase(studentnum) = UCase(cell.Value) Then
        r = cell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next
For Each cell In Range("quizzes")
    If UCase(quiznum) = UCase(cell.Value) Then
        c = cell.Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Cells(r, c).Font.Color = vbBlue
```

And your step 4 will be something like:

```
Cells(r, "M").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC3:RC12)"
```

(I'm guessing which columns you are trying to average, so used C:L.)

---

*Please remember that the Stack Overflow licensing requires any use of this answer in your own work to contain an attribution referring back to this answer - so, if this **isn't** just a practice test, make sure you tell your teacher that the answer was written partly by me!*

Comment: thank you very much. this is strictly a practice test and no answer key exists for it as there are many ways to do it. i'm not turning it in anywhere so no worries, just for me. thanks again!!